# Spatial commodities data global

Tags: data-request, geospatial, food

I'm looking for data on commodities (corn and potato). Tools such as USDA's [cropscape](http://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/) are great but lack global cover.
I found [this dataset](http://www.earthstat.org/data-download/), but it is for the year 2000 and not very recent.

Are you guys aware of any better datasets containing the location of commodity crops, such as corn and potato?

Comment: Did you search http://data.fao.org/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the SPAM data out of the International Food Policy Research Institute?

http://mapspam.info/

I don't know if you're looking for the same resolution as the CropScape data, but SPAM produces 5' estimates of physical area, harvested area, production and yield on 42 crops globally circa 2000 and 2005.

Answer (score 1):

The UN COMTRADE database has extensive information relating to trade in commodities between countries.

http://comtrade.un.org/db/

This link is to World Bank's forecasts on commodity markets:

http://econ.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/EXTDEC/EXTDECPROSPECTS/0,,contentMDK:21574907~menuPK:7859231~pagePK:64165401~piPK:64165026~theSitePK:476883,00.html

Comment: thanks for the comment but these datasets dont have spatial distribution on a sub country level. I'm looking for raster data.